# Node promise-chaining causes too many return statements in function

Tags: node.js, promise

Asuming the next reset password function:

```
function forgotPassword(email){
  return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    return User.findByMail(email);
  }).then(function(user){
    if (!user) {
      return Promise.reject({message: 'Cannot find user with that email'});
    }

    return [user, tokensService.createRandomBytes()];
 }).spread(function(user, token){
    user.resetPasswordToken = token;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour
    return [user.saveAsync(), token];
  }).spread(function(user, token){
    return emailService.sendResetPassword(user.email, token);
  });
}
```

The caller of this function expects a promise as a return value.

But my question is:
Is that the right way to chain promises?

It looks to me like all the return statements make the code look unreadable.

Is there a way to avoid that? And is there a way to avoid the `return Promise.resolve().then...` at the start?

PS. I am using `bluebird` as promise lib

UPDATE:

After Dans answer I did the following:

```
function login(email, password) {
  return User.findByMail(email).then(function(user){
    return [user.comparePassword(password), user];
  })
}
```

And i keep getting Undefined is not a function, here is the stack trace:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.login (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/src/authentication/authentication-controller.js:17:11)
at /home/royi/projects/travessey-api/src/authentication/authentication-router.js:8:18
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at Function.handle (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
at router (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at allowCrossDomains (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/src/authentication/authentication-middleware.js:34:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at /home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express-validator/lib/express_validator.js:228:5
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at urlencodedParser (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:81:44)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/royi/projects/travessey-api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

Comment: You can use a callback fonction

Comment: @JohnSmith Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sorry. I'm on my phone but you can try something like this 
`forgotPassword(email, (result, error) => { if (err) {... }; //do stuff with result} )`
then
`function forgotPassword(email, callback)  { return Promise.resolve(...).then((resultResolve) => {callback(resultResolve)}).catch((err) =>{callback(null, new Error(err)) }) ; } `

Comment: Or maybe I completely missunderstood your question

Comment: Is `tokensService.createRandomBytes()` a promise? What about `user.saveAsync()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks to me like all the return statements make the code look unreadable. Is there a way to avoid that?

Two ways actually, but none of them works in ES5:

- arrow functions don't need an explicit `return` if you've got only one expression:

  ```
  const forgotPassword = (email) => 
    Promise.resolve().then(() =>
      User.findByMail(email)
    ).then(user =>
      user
        ? [user, tokensService.createRandomBytes()]
        : Promise.reject({message: 'Cannot find user with that email'})
    ).spread((user, token) => {
      user.resetPasswordToken = token;
      user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour
      return [user.saveAsync(), token];
    }).spread((user, token) => 
      emailService.sendResetPassword(user.email, token);
    );
  ```
- async functions allow you to dodge `then` completely and streamline everything using the `await` keyword:

  ```
  async function forgotPassword(email) {
    await Promise.resolve();
    let user = await User.findByMail(email);
    if (!user)
      throw new Error('Cannot find user with that email');

    let token = tokensService.createRandomBytes();
    user.resetPasswordToken = token;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour
    user = await user.saveAsync();
    return emailService.sendResetPassword(user.email, token);
  }
  ```

  They are a ES8-proposed feature, but you can already use them in your transpiler. With Bluebird, you can also use generators similarly, see the [`Promise.coroutine` docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html).

> And is there a way to avoid the return Promise.resolve().then... at the start?

Yes. You can just start your chain with the first promise-returning function:

```
function forgotPassword(email){
  return User.findByMail(email).then(function(user){
    if (!user) {
      …
```

and if you are not sure whether it returns a promise, you can alternatively use

```
function forgotPassword(email){
  return Promise.resolve(User.findByMail(email)).then(function(user){
    if (!user) {
      …
```

The differences (exception handling, asynchrony) to your current solution are minuscule.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not true when `User.findByMail(email)` results in a value and not a promise:

> You could easily remove the first one as:
>
> ```
> return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
>   return User.findByMail(email);
> })
> ```
>
> Is the same as:
>
> ```
> return User.findByMail(email)
> ```

As it doesn't:

```
return Promise.resolve(User.findByMail(email))
```

would wrap that value as a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to chain for the sake of chaining:

```
function forgotPassword(email) {
  return Promise.all([
    User.findByMail(email),
    // creating an unrelated random token doesn't have to be done later
    tokensService.createRandomBytes()
  ]).spread(function(user, token) {
    if (!user) {
      // equivalent to your Promise.reject() but cleaner
      // and err.message == 'Cannot find user with that email'
      throw new Error('Cannot find user with that email');
    }

    user.resetPasswordToken = token;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

    // nothing wrong with one level of nesting
    return user.save().then(function(usr) {
      return emailService.sendResetPassword(user.email, token);
    })
  });
}
```